# Are solvable groups Howson?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

A finitely generated group $G$ has the *Howson property* if the intersection of any two finitely generated subgroups is again finitely generated. (Finitely generated) free groups, nilpotent, and polycyclic groups all have the Howson property.

Are solvable groups Howson?

I cannot find a reference to this. I expect the answer to be negative, but can't think of any counterexample at the moment.

Comment: How solvable groups Arson?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Solve group arson how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $H = {\rm BS}(1,k) = \langle  a,b \mid b^{-1}ab=a^k \rangle$ for some $k>1$.

Then $H$ is solvable, and the normal subgroup $\langle a^H \rangle$ is abelian and not finitely generated.

Now let $G = \langle  a,b,c \mid b^{-1}ab=a^k, [c,b] = [c,a] = 1\rangle \cong H \times {\mathbb Z}$.

Then the subgroups $\langle a,b \rangle$ and $\langle a,bc \rangle$ of $G$ are finitely generated, but their intersection $\langle a^H \rangle$ is not.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This is of course the same trick as for showing that $\mathbb{Z} \times F_2$ is not Howson; I should have realised that such an idea would work here too.

Comment: In the presentation of $G$, should $[b,a]=1$ be $[b,c]=1$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, thanks, corrected.